# How do I execute a function only if one part of the UI receives input?

Tags: flask

So far I have this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def first():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.get_json()

        text1 = body['text1 ']
        text2 = body['text2']
        someFunction(text1)
        otherFunction(text2)
```

But what if I want to only execute a function only if a certain part of the UI receives input? Say that only when the user puts something into the `text2` box, that `otherFunction` is executed. So far, everytime I POST, both are executed.

So I guess I'm looking for something like?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def first():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.get_json()

        if request.method.box1:
            text1 = body['text1']
            someFunction(text1)
       if request.method.box1:
            text2 = body['text2']
            otherFunction(text2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost right, but `request.method` won't have `box1` attribute.

So this will be correct way:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def first():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.get_json()

        if body.get('text1'):
            someFunction(body['text1'])
        if body.get('text2'):
            otherFunction(body['text2'])
```